# Eclipse - Project contains error(s) but none seen

Tags: java, android

My project has been running fine for weeks. I went to swap out an image today and suddenly eclipse highlighted my project saying it contained errors but did not point to any particular files. I then cleans the project and now it is bringing up the message

> R cannot be resolved to a variable

The gen folder is empty and I have these errors now over all my src folder. Does anyone know what to do?

All help appreciated.

Comment: eclipse sometimes mixes up things. Make a clean again and rebuild the project. Then the gen/ folder should be regenerated as well as R.java
If you have clicked the option build automatically, you might want to make a little change somewhere and hit save in order to trigger building. 

Also what works for me when this happens is closing the project and the reopening it.

Comment: by rebuild you are referring to just running the project? I have tried this a number of times, opening and closing eclipse and multiple cleans

Comment: no by rebuild I mean select the project from the navigator/package explorer in eclipse, hit the Project Menu and click build.
Try closing the project, not eclipse :) (right click on the project "close project")

Comment: Try *touching* your Android manifest and maybe one of your resource files and seeing if that shakes it out. Add a character, remove it and save. Try rebuild.

Comment: just tried changing something simple and saving. Plus closing all project files that were open then reopening. Nothing changed sadly

Comment: Tried "touching" both the manifest and some resource files to no avail. Thanks for the tip

Comment: no, the was a misunderstanding. Closing the files that were open is not the same as closing the project :)

Comment: what do you mean by close the project then ? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project has an error and can not build thats why Android compiler can not generate the R class and eclipse warns you about that class. Check out all problems in the problems view. Also check project runtime and library settings if there is anything missing. You might accidentaly delete a lib or java runtime might have been changed.

Comment: thanks I never knew about the problems view. I deleted the final error which was about aapt then made a change to an xml file. This immediately brought up an error that I have duplicate images called the same thing in my res folder, but eclipse had not picked up on this

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter this king of 'weird' issues with *.xml resources I add one more item. I case of strings.xml I add new item and that CTRL+S the project will be rebuild and the R class will be refreshed. This usually fix the problems, and afterwards I delete the item that I added.

There are a lot of times when eclipese doesn't rebuild until you add something new (that it , until you make a change in your resources)

I hope this will help you if not , it might help to someone else having similar problems

Answer (score 0):

If you did not disable the built-in Source history in Eclipse (right click on a file in Explorer view, then select Replace With -> Local History), revert to the code prior to your change, and rebuild. If it builds, figure out what the change was and adjust accordingly.

If you don't have that history, try to remember from memory. Likely it can't build the R file because one of your XML resource file is incorrect or references the wrong file.